# Get Components In Display Order

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcomponent

Is there a way to get a list of components within a JPanel according to the order that they display in the JPanel (Top left to bottom right), and not the order that they were added to the JPanel?

This seems to get the components in the order that they were added to the panel

```
Component[] comps = myJPanel.getComponents();
```

Comment: You could possibly use `getComponentAt(x, y)` and iterate through the component's points, adding every component (that hasn't already been found) to a list.  Just a theory.

Comment: *"Is there a way to get a list of components within a JPanel according to the order that they display in the JPanel (Top left to bottom right)"*  Sure. Add all the components to a list structure then sort them according to a Comparator that accounts for the position.  OTOH I am rather curious as to what you are actually trying to achieve from such futzing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [`Container#getFocusTraversalPolicy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getFocusTraversalPolicy%28%29), which returns a [`FocusTraversalPolicy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FocusTraversalPolicy.html) which has methods to determine the focus movement through a container.

This (should) provide you with the natural order of the components (from the perspective of the layout manager and focus manager)

I'd start with [`FocusTraversalPolicy#getFirstComponent(Container)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FocusTraversalPolicy.html#getFirstComponent%28java.awt.Container%29) and [`FocusTraversalPolicy#getComponentAfter(Container, Component)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FocusTraversalPolicy.html#getComponentAfter%28java.awt.Container,%20java.awt.Component%29)

If that doesn't work, you may need to write your self a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and sort the array of components accordingly

**UPDATED - Focus Traversal Example**

```
public class ComponentOrder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ComponentOrder();
    }

    public ComponentOrder() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                BodyPane body = new BodyPane();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(body);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                Container focusRoot = body.getFocusCycleRootAncestor();
                FocusTraversalPolicy ftp = focusRoot.getFocusTraversalPolicy();
                Component comp = ftp.getFirstComponent(body);
                Component first = comp;
                while (comp != null) {
                    System.out.println(" - " + comp);
                    comp = ftp.getComponentAfter(focusRoot, comp);
                    if (comp.equals(first)) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class BodyPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField fldFirstName;
        private JTextField fldMiddleName;
        private JTextField fldLastName;
        private JTextField fldDateOfBirth;
        private JTextField fldEMail;
        private JButton okButton;
        private JButton cancelButton;

        public BodyPane() {

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(createFieldsPane());
            add(createButtonsPane(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        }

        public JPanel createButtonsPane() {

            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
            panel.add((okButton = createButton("Ok")));
            panel.add((cancelButton = createButton("Cancel")));

            return panel;

        }

        protected JButton createButton(String text) {

            return new JButton(text);

        }

        public JPanel createFieldsPane() {

            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

            panel.add(createLabel("First Name:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            panel.add(createLabel("Middle Name:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            panel.add(createLabel("Last Name:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            panel.add(createLabel("Date of Birth:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            panel.add(createLabel("EMail:"), gbc);

            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            panel.add((fldFirstName = createField()), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            panel.add((fldLastName = createField()), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            panel.add((fldMiddleName = createField()), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            panel.add((fldDateOfBirth = createField()), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            panel.add((fldEMail = createField()), gbc);

            JPanel filler = new JPanel();
            filler.setOpaque(false);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            panel.add(filler, gbc);

            return panel;

        }

        protected JLabel createLabel(String text) {

            return new JLabel(text);

        }

        protected JTextField createField() {

            JTextField field = new JTextField(12);
            return field;

        }
    }
}
```

### Comparator example

The following example uses a comparator to determine the flow of the components.  This version translates all the components from a parent container into that containers coordinate space, so it should be possible to use this with compound containers.

*nb* I stole the comparator from `javax.swing.LayoutComparator` which is package protected (which was nice of the SwingTeam) and modified it to convert the component coordinates back into the parent coordinate space

```
public class ComponentOrder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ComponentOrder();
    }

    public ComponentOrder() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                BodyPane body = new BodyPane();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(body);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                List<Component> components = new ArrayList<Component>(25);
                getContents(body, components);
                LayoutComparator lc = new LayoutComparator(body);
                lc.setComponentOrientation(body.getComponentOrientation());
                Collections.sort(components, lc);
                for (Component comp : components) {
                    System.out.println(comp);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    protected void getContents(Container container, List<Component> components) {
        for (Component comp : container.getComponents()) {
            components.add(comp);
            if (comp instanceof Container) {
                getContents((Container) comp, components);
            }
        }
    }

    public class BodyPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField fldFirstName;
        private JTextField fldMiddleName;
        private JTextField fldLastName;
        private JTextField fldDateOfBirth;
        private JTextField fldEMail;
        private JButton okButton;
        private JButton cancelButton;

        public BodyPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(createFieldsPane());
            add(createButtonsPane(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

        public JPanel createButtonsPane() {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
            panel.add((okButton = createButton("Ok")));
            panel.add((cancelButton = createButton("Cancel")));
            return panel;
        }

        protected JButton createButton(String text) {
            return new JButton(text);
        }

        public JPanel createFieldsPane() {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;

            panel.add(createLabel("First Name:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            panel.add(createLabel("Middle Name:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            panel.add(createLabel("Last Name:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            panel.add(createLabel("Date of Birth:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            panel.add(createLabel("EMail:"), gbc);

            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            panel.add((fldFirstName = createField("FirstName")), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            panel.add((fldLastName = createField("LastName")), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            panel.add((fldMiddleName = createField("MiddleName")), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            panel.add((fldDateOfBirth = createField("DateOfBirth")), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            panel.add((fldEMail = createField("EMail")), gbc);

            JPanel filler = new JPanel();
            filler.setOpaque(false);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            panel.add(filler, gbc);

            return panel;
        }

        protected JLabel createLabel(String text) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
            label.setName(text);
            return label;
        }

        protected JTextField createField(String name) {
            JTextField field = new JTextField(12);
            field.setName("Field-" + name);
            return field;
        }
    }

    public class LayoutComparator implements Comparator<Component>, java.io.Serializable {

        private static final int ROW_TOLERANCE = 10;
        private boolean horizontal = true;
        private boolean leftToRight = true;

        private Component parent;

        public LayoutComparator(Component parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        void setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation orientation) {
            horizontal = orientation.isHorizontal();
            leftToRight = orientation.isLeftToRight();
        }

        public int compare(Component a, Component b) {
            if (a == b) {
                return 0;
            }

            // Row/Column algorithm only applies to siblings. If 'a' and 'b'
            // aren't siblings, then we need to find their most inferior
            // ancestors which share a parent. Compute the ancestory lists for
            // each Component and then search from the Window down until the
            // hierarchy branches.
            if (a.getParent() != b.getParent()) {
                LinkedList<Component> aAncestory = new LinkedList<Component>();

                for (; a != null; a = a.getParent()) {
                    aAncestory.add(a);
                    if (a instanceof Window) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (a == null) {
                    // 'a' is not part of a Window hierarchy. Can't cope.
                    throw new ClassCastException();
                }

                LinkedList<Component> bAncestory = new LinkedList<Component>();

                for (; b != null; b = b.getParent()) {
                    bAncestory.add(b);
                    if (b instanceof Window) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (b == null) {
                    // 'b' is not part of a Window hierarchy. Can't cope.
                    throw new ClassCastException();
                }

                for (ListIterator<Component> aIter = aAncestory.listIterator(aAncestory.size()),
                                bIter = bAncestory.listIterator(bAncestory.size());;) {
                    if (aIter.hasPrevious()) {
                        a = aIter.previous();
                    } else {
                        // a is an ancestor of b
                        return -1;
                    }

                    if (bIter.hasPrevious()) {
                        b = bIter.previous();
                    } else {
                        // b is an ancestor of a
                        return 1;
                    }

                    if (a != b) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            Point pa = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(a, a.getLocation(), parent);
            Point pb = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(b, b.getLocation(), parent);

            int ax = pa.x, ay = pa.y, bx = pb.x, by = pb.y;

            int zOrder = a.getParent().getComponentZOrder(a) - b.getParent().getComponentZOrder(b);
            if (horizontal) {
                if (leftToRight) {

                    // LT - Western Europe (optional for Japanese, Chinese, Korean)

                    if (Math.abs(ay - by) < ROW_TOLERANCE) {
                        return (ax < bx) ? -1 : ((ax > bx) ? 1 : zOrder);
                    } else {
                        return (ay < by) ? -1 : 1;
                    }
                } else { // !leftToRight

                    // RT - Middle East (Arabic, Hebrew)

                    if (Math.abs(ay - by) < ROW_TOLERANCE) {
                        return (ax > bx) ? -1 : ((ax < bx) ? 1 : zOrder);
                    } else {
                        return (ay < by) ? -1 : 1;
                    }
                }
            } else { // !horizontal
                if (leftToRight) {

                    // TL - Mongolian

                    if (Math.abs(ax - bx) < ROW_TOLERANCE) {
                        return (ay < by) ? -1 : ((ay > by) ? 1 : zOrder);
                    } else {
                        return (ax < bx) ? -1 : 1;
                    }
                } else { // !leftToRight

                    // TR - Japanese, Chinese, Korean

                    if (Math.abs(ax - bx) < ROW_TOLERANCE) {
                        return (ay < by) ? -1 : ((ay > by) ? 1 : zOrder);
                    } else {
                        return (ax > bx) ? -1 : 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using this: `Component c1 = focus.getFirstComponent(layers)` where layers is a JPanel, and I am getting a nullPointerException. Any ideas why?

Comment: @RyanNaddy does it have compound components?

Answer (score 0):

While the solutions submitted earlier are ingenious, the method which (overall) meets most of my requirements is rather more simplistic, and relies on having a window architecture has the zero-zero (root) point in the upper-left.

Since the exact coding will depend on which libraries you choose to use, let me describe the ensuing process heuristically:

The distance from the origin for any point `(x,y)` is `(x^2 + y^2)**(0.5)`.  Using this one can construct a shadow array which mirrors each pair with a single number.  By simply doing a relational ascending sort of each of these distances, one can arrive at a fairly good approximation of the top-left to bottom-right order.

There are some pathological examples which should be avoided (or at least understood).  For example, using a compass with its point at the upper left apex of the screen will generate an infinite number of points exactly the same distance from the origin.

To deal with this one can simply prescale either the `x` or `y` value with a multiplier before squaring it and combining it with the other unit squared as described.  This will give proportionately more value to a `"y"` which is higher than an `x` which is closer to the left edge of the window, or vice-versa as required.